# Awk stopping printing at "

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I'm making an awk script to convert a csv of aliases into a shell script to apply them, but I'm having an issue where awk seems to be stopping at a `"` in the second field. The command I'm running is

```
awk -F"," '{print("alias " $1 "=\"" $2"\"")}' ~/repos/dotfiles/aliases.csv >~/repos/dotfiles/.aliases.sh
```

and the contents of `aliases.csv` is

```
updateAlias,awk -F"," '{print "alias " $1 "=" $2}' ~/repos/dotfiles/aliases.csv >~/repos/dotfiles/.aliases.sh
```

This is giving the output

```
alias updateAlias="awk -F""
```

which is obviously not what I want. This is my first time using awk for anything other than printing columns, so it's probably something obvious and/or dumb.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and how I can fix it?

Comment: The entire second field is literally `awk -F"`.

Comment: I am indeed a fool. Do I just need to add a \ before the comma to escape it?